# In Windows command prompt, copy one file (or multiple files) to multiple directories that have a user specified name

Tags: python, copy, directory

Quite a few times each month, I have to copy a set of files from one folder to multiple folders. As the amount of folders to copy the files to is constantly increasing, I've been trying to find a way to automate the copy process. My problem is that I need to copy the files only to folders with a certain name.

The folder structure is approximately like this:

A
--- B
------ C1
--------- D
------ C2
--------- D
------ C3
--------- D

and so on.

The files must be copied to the D folders (they all share the same name).

Any solution (preferably Win 7 command prompt or Python) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

src = 'source_folder'
name = 'D_folder_name'

#In your case this would be something like C:\\A
top = 'root_folder for destination'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    if name in dirs:
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(src, '*.*')):
            shutil.copy(filename, os.path.join(root,name))
```

Just FYI: This is written in python 3.3

Comment: Thank you, I will give this one a try today as I need to perform this operation once again.

Comment: And based on a quick test, it is working as needed. Thanks a lot, this will save me a lot of manual work in the future!